# Pyqt5: How to timeout Qtimer in QTread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

**I want to design a timer that uses a flag to trigger the timer, and then start the timer count or stop the timer count. I tried some methods to fix it, but it was not triggered. Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Here are my codes below:**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Clock_Window, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        File_path = os.path.abspath(default_path)

        self.total_sec_count = 0
        self.total_min_count = 0
        self.total_hr_count = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.do_timer_timeout)

        self.BTN_Start.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)
        self.BTN_Stop.clicked.connect(self.stopTimer)
        self.BTN_Zero.clicked.connect(self.zeroTimer)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker_Qthread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.start()
    def do_timer_timeout(self):
        self.lcd_Second.display(str(self.total_sec_count))
        self.lcd_Minute.display(str(self.total_min_count))
        self.lcd_Hour.display(str(self.total_hr_count))
        self.total_sec_count += 1
        if self.total_sec_count > 59:
            self.total_sec_count = 0
            self.total_min_count += 1
        if self.total_min_count > 59:
            self.total_min_count = 0
            self.total_hr_count += 1
    def startTimer(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)
    def stopTimer(self):
        self.timer.stop()
    def detectTime(self):
        while True:
            if os.path.isfile(File_path+"\\start.flag"):
                time.sleep(3)
                os.remove(File_path+"\\start.flag")
                self.startTimer()
            if os.path.isfile(File_path+"\\end.flag"):
                time.sleep(3)
                os.remove(File_path+"\\end.flag")
                self.stopTimer()
    
class Worker_Qthread(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    def run(self):
        window.detectTime()
        self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear to me. Can you try to explain what do you mean by "I want to design a timer that uses a flag to trigger the timer, and then start the timer count or stop the timer count"? Also note that: 1. QMainWindow already inherits from QWidget, remove it from the class definition; 2. You cannot start/stop a QTimer that has been created in another thread.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clearly. A flag will be generated when another program starts and ends. I hope to use this flag to calculate the execution total time and another function is to calculate the time through the button. Thanks for your suggestions, I will revise these parts.

Comment: How is the other program started? If it's started programmatically, consider using [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html). If it's not, you can use [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) to monitor file creation (in a watched directory) or deletion (once the file has been created).